# UIButton Selector in addTarget called without user interaction

Tags: swift, uibutton, selector

I'm struggling in a problem with the method addTarget for an UIButton.

```
spotifyButton.socialButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector(Social.openUrl(Constants.URLs.SpotifyApp, fallback: Constants.URLs.SpotifyWeb)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

This code is inside the viewDidLoad of a UIViewController the problem is that the method inside the Selector is called without the user interaction.
Could you please help me to solve this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can use custom parameters in the function defined inside the selector. The method signature should look like `openUrl(sender: AnyObject)`